# MVC4 accessing method of one controller to the other

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap

I have some inbuilt method in `BootstrapBaseController.cs` like

```
public void Success(string message)
{
    TempData.Add(Alerts.SUCCESS, message);
}
```

I haven't used it yet but I guess it shows some success message that i pass to this method.
I want to use this method in my other controller called `PortalController`. In following method I want to show success message when a user is added to database.

Suggestions?

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel user)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid && (user.Password == user.ConfirmPassword))
            {
                var regUser = _db.Users.Create();

                regUser.UserName = user.UserName;
                regUser.Password = user.Password;

                _db.Users.Add(regUser);
                _db.SaveChanges();
            }
            return View();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to make `PortalController` inherits from `BootstrapBaseController`.

```
public class PortalController : BootstrapBaseController
```

If this is not an option you may need to move that common method to a third class used by both controllers.

Comment: Thanks, but I just realised I'm not being forwarded to [HttpPost] action when the Register button is pressed. On clicking register button it still forwards me to [HttpGet] action. may be need to as new qusetion.

Comment: ummm how do I show the success message if I return something like this return RedirectToAction("Index","Home") to my [httpPost] metod. my register view uses _BootstrapLayout.empty.cshtml as Layout

Answer (score 0):

1. Make PortalController inherit from BootstrapBaseController
2. Before returning the View call Sucess and set the message
3. On your _layout.cshtml view (and I'm assuming all your views inherit use this layout) check for that temp variable and display your message

Updated Controller method:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register(RegisterModel user)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid && (user.Password == user.ConfirmPassword))
    {
        var regUser = _db.Users.Create();

        regUser.UserName = user.UserName;
        regUser.Password = user.Password;

        _db.Users.Add(regUser);
        _db.SaveChanges();
    }
    Success("User Created successfully");

    return View();
}
```

_Layout.cshtml

```
@if (TempData["VariableName"] != null)
    {
        <div>@TempData["VariableName"]</div>
    }
```

Comment: Actually i use another layout but I figured i'm not being forwared to `[httpPost]` on button click of `register` view. So, after I fix this i'll try what you mentioned

Comment: ummm how do I show the success message if I return something like this `return RedirectToAction("Index","Home")` my register view uses `_BootstrapLayout.empty.cshtml` as Layout

Comment: Just put the code that checks for the TempData property on the layout. The TempData will be available and passed to the new action